# Split In Java with condition

Tags: java, string, split

Split the string in java:-
I tried with the following code but not getting the expected o/p

```
 String[] SplitString = s.split(" ");
 String s= "Apple not in Vegetable,Object,Item"
 Expected o/p = Apple
 Expected o/p = not in
 Expected o/p = Vegetable,Object,Item
```

Comment: You are splitting by space, how do you expect `not in` to come as single string? There's a space here.

Comment: the output should be Apple \n not \n in \n Vegetable,Object,Item

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet

```
        String[] SplitString = s.split(" ");
        for (String value : SplitString) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
```

space between **not in** string so it will split into **not** and then **in** string.
Expected output:->

```
Apple
not
in
Vegetable,Object,Item
```

Comment: Yes you are right, then how can I get the expected O/P?